# cannot assign *pubsub.Topic to mytopic (type custom) in multiple assignment

Tags: go, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to create two simple createTopic() and sendMessage() functions in Go using the package gocloud.dev/pubsub

However, I get an error saying
./topic.go:18:15: cannot assign *pubsub.Topic to mytopic (type mytopic) in multiple assignment

The code looks as follows:

```
main.go

package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    _ "gocloud.dev/pubsub/mempubsub"
)

func main() {

    mytopic := mytopic{}
    ctx := context.Background()
    mytopic, err := createTopic(ctx, "mem://topicA")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error occured", err)
    }

    mytopic.sendMessage(ctx, "hello")
}
```

```
topic.go

package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "gocloud.dev/pubsub"
    _ "gocloud.dev/pubsub/mempubsub"
)

type mytopic struct {
    pubsub.Topic
}

func createTopic(ctx context.Context, url string) (mytopic, error) {

    mytopic := mytopic{}
    mytopic, err := pubsub.OpenTopic(ctx, "mempubsub")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not open topic: %v", err)
    }
    defer mytopic.Shutdown(ctx)
    return mytopic, err
}

func (t mytopic) sendMessage(ctx context.Context, m string) error {

    err := t.Send(ctx, &pubsub.Message{
        Body: []byte("Hello, World!\n"),
        Metadata: map[string]string{
            "language":   "en",
            "importance": "high",
        },
    })

    return err

}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error message describes the problem well. Here's the fix:

Use a pointer field:

```
type mytopic struct {
    *pubsub.Topic
}
```

Assign the return value from pubsub.OpenTopic to the field:

```
var err error
var mytopic mytopic
mytopic.Topic, err := pubsub.OpenTopic(ctx, "mempubsub")
```